# Where is the class "DataItem" and "CustomGrid" defined in Blazor FluentUI component documentation?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, fluent-ui

I am referring to the documentation of Blazor FluentUI here - https://blazorfluentui.azurewebsites.net/listPage. In List components, documentation refers to the class "DataItem" and "CustomGrid" but I could not find them in the doc. Where is their implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All demo pages are in the github [repo](https://github.com/BlazorFluentUI/BlazorFluentUI):

- [ListPage](https://github.com/BlazorFluentUI/BlazorFluentUI/blob/main/Demo/BlazorFluentUI.Demo.Shared/Pages/ListPage.razor)
- [DataItem](https://github.com/BlazorFluentUI/BlazorFluentUI/blob/main/Demo/BlazorFluentUI.Demo.Shared/Models/DataItem.cs)
- [CustomGrid](https://github.com/BlazorFluentUI/BlazorFluentUI/blob/main/Demo/BlazorFluentUI.Demo.Shared/Models/CustomGrid.cs)